# ArrayList with formatting

Tags: java, arraylist, filesaver.js

Struggling with my ArrayList code. 
I needed to generate 20 random numbers between 1 and 200. 
It works but when I show all in array list it, it all comes out horizontal
(ie: [190.9873874849,3.45694033,67.900034...] and SUPER long. It needs to have each number print out in a list format, with the only four digits after the decimal. (%10.4)

I tried this:

```
    System.out.printf("%10.4", num[0]);
```

which works for the formatting but I can't seem to get the whole arraylist to work.

My array is this:

```
    ArrayList<Number> num = new ArrayList<Number>();

    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
        num.add(Math.random() *200 +1);
        }
```

It works like I said for getting and listing the numbers -- but not in the "correct" way.

I also have to save the numbers to a file, and be able to let the user choose an index for them and tell them their number they chose from the file, which I am also struggling with.

Any help would be amazing!!!

[EDIT] 
This worked (from Ole V.V.):

```
        for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) {
        num.add(Math.random() *200 +1);
        System.out.printf("%10.4f%n", num.get(i));
```

[ADDITIONAL] 
**I have to post here and can't make a new question because some jerk downvoted me? **

I have all of the numbers in my array read in and saved to a text file (with the right formatting!) but now I have to be able to ask the user for an index, and be able to find the object according to that index... but it isn't working!

I don't know how to assign indexes to variables when the numbers are no longer in array format (they're in a column similar to what is in the column).

Comment: *It needs to have each number print out in a list format* what does it mean??

Comment: print out in list format can you explain this?

Comment: Please provide your Expected output

Comment: You need to iterate over the list

Comment: Sorry -- it needs to show each number in the array using the console (so println, print, printf...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a couple of options. First, you may use a `for` loop like the one you already have:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        System.out.printf("%10.4f%n", num.get(i));
    }
```

A terser option is:

```
    num.forEach(n -> System.out.printf("%10.4f%n", n));
```

In both case the output goes like

```
  186.8143
  129.4201
  169.7405
  ...
```

Your format string, `%10.4`, was almost correct. You need to add `f` for formatting a floating-point number. I also added `%n` for a line break after the number. In Java `num[i]` works only for arrays, not for `ArrayList`, you need `num.get(i)`.

Comment: THANK YOU!! IT WORKED!!! I didn't realize I left things out! Thank you thank you thank you!!!

Answer (score -1):

You need to trim the extra digits by this simple trick.

```
 double number = Math.random()*200 + 1;
 number = (long)( number * 10000 );
 number = number / 10000;
```